# Sidebar disappears when I make the window smaller! New development, was working fine before!

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, rwd-theme, sidebar

I have been working on this site:

http://greenlivingaustralia.com.au/shop

I simply edited the default rwd template in Magento to suit my needs.

I used the Codnitive Sidebar Navigation Menu Professional extension to move my menu from the top to the left sidebar and got everything working beautifully.

The navigation was breaking down well when the window was resized, turning into a beautiful accordion.

Now, suddenly, the menu is disappearing when I resize the window smaller.

I haven't changed much since the breakdown except for a few things in the header, to my knowledge. I reverted those changes and something is still amiss.

Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently the class "no-display" is being added to the <div> which includes the navigation when it is smaller than 770px, however, I cannot figure out where this is coming from. I just went ahead and killed the style "no-display" in the main css file for the theme. This allows the menu to remain but it may be affecting other parts of the site as well. Any clue why it is being set to "no-display" in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I just answered this question here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/34974/2142

In short, it is being caused by the jQuery.toggleSingle plugin defined in app.js and can be prevented by modifying the "Block collapsing (on smaller viewports)" section of that file, per my comment above.

Also, I'd encourage you to learn about awesome Chrome's "DOM Modification" breakpoints to help debug issues like this in the future.